# using inline javascript inside a python loop

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a list of entries.  Insider the list of entries I have a link to individual entries. I have an update form that updates one field.

I want to open the update form inside a new window.  The user then submits the form is directed to a success page which currently has a timed close.

The issue I am encountering is with the inline JavaScript which opens the form in a new window.  When I attempt to assign the kwarg on the URL it the JavaScript does not change with each entry in the list.

I have limited JavaScript, and jQuery knowledge.

I just want the JavaScript to open a new window for each update form.

I have included the template below.

````
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Script No.</th>
                    <th>Entered on</th>
                    <th>Patient</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Form</th>
                    <th>Units</th>
                    <th>Dispensing Price</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Dispatch Date</th>
                    <th>Entered by</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 {% for script in scripts %}
                 <tr>
                  <td>{{script.pk}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.entered_on}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.patient}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.patient.email}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.product}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.product.form.description}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.quantity}}</td>
                  <td>$&nbsp;{{ script.dispensing_price }}</td>
                  {% if script.dispatch_date is not none %}
                  <td>{{script.get_script_status_display}}</td>
                  {% else %}
                  <td><a href = "{% url "script:script_update_status" script.pk %}">{{script.get_script_status_display}}</a></td>
                  {% endif %}
                  <td><a href ="#" onclick="updateStatus()" style="float:right;">
                    <script>var url = "{% url "script:script_update_status" script.pk %}"; 
                    function updateStatus() {var myWindow = window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=250");}
                  </script></td>
                  {% if script.dispatch_date is none %}
                  <td>Not Sent</td>
                  {% else %}
                  <td>{{script.dispatch_date}}</td>
                  {% endif %}
                  <td>{{script.created_by.first_name}}&nbsp;{{script.created_by.last_name}}</td>
                  <td><small><a href = "{% url 'script:script_detail' script.pk %}">View</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="{% url "script:script_update" script.pk %}">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'label:product_label' script.pk %}">Lab Label</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'label:dispense_label' script.pk %}">Dispense Label
                  </a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'label:shipping_label' script.pk %}">Shipping Label</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url "label:receipt" script.pk %}" >Health Fund Receipt</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url "label:repeat" script.pk %}">Repeat</a></small></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table> ```
Kind Regards

AC
````

Comment: The issue is you're defining lots and lots of `updateStatus()` functions. The browser is lenient, so it will call the first one instead of refusing to do anything. A quick and dirty fix is to add something unique to the function name. A better solution is to use a single <script> to handle all button clicks.

Comment: Here's a clean solution (without inline code): https://jsfiddle.net/b6ngzeLs/

Comment: Chris G the jsfiddle.net/b6ngzels didn't work.  I think the better option is to define and add something unique that is based on the pk.  But I can't get the script.pk to to output properly in the loop when included inside the script tags such that javascript can then use a variable to construct its urls.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Did you inspect the HTML generated by your python code in the browser? It might simply be a syntax problem.

Comment: Chris G you were correct syntax error was the cause of the problem.  The table ID was wrong.  Once changed this worked.  Thankyou for your help

Comment: Great, you're welcome :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71435925/how-to-select-different-modelforms-based-on-select-value-for-django-model-form