# How to select different ModelForms based on select value for DJANGO model form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a list of values.  Within the list of values is a status which has a hyperlink to a particular model form.

I want to dynamically change the hyperlink based on the select value to direct the user to different forms based on the select value.

So, for example, when the Model value is pending, I want the hyperlink to go to the pending form.  When the status is invoice sent and the use clicks the hyperlink I want the user to to go to the payment form.

The code is below

````
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]' data-page-length='25'><button onClick="refreshPage()" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" title="Refresh"><i class="fa fa-sync"></i></button>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Script No.</th>
                    <th>Entered on</th>
                    <th>Script Type</th>
                    <th>Patient</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Contact No</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Form</th>
                    <th>Units</th>
                    <th>Dispensing Price</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Dispatch Date</th>
                    <th>Worksheet ID</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 {% for script in scripts %}
                 <tr>
                  <td>{{script.pk}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.entered_on}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.get_script_type_display}}
                  <td>{{script.patient}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.patient.address}}&nbsp;{{script.patient.city}}&nbsp;{{script.patient.AU_states}}&nbsp;{{script.patient.postal_code}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.patient.email}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.patient.mobile_number}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.product}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.product.form.description}}</td>
                  <td>{{script.quantity}}</td>
                  <td>$&nbsp;{{ script.dispensing_price }}</td>
                  {% if script.dispatch_date is not none %}
                  <td>{{script.get_script_status_display}}</td>
                  {% else %}
                  <td> <a class="edit" href="#" data-url="{% url "script:script_update_status" script.pk %}">{{script.get_script_status_display}}</a></td>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if script.dispatch_date is none %}
                  <td>Not Sent</td>
                  {% else %}
                  <td>{{script.dispatch_date}}</td>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if script.document_id is none %}
                  <td>Not Made</td>
                  {% else %}
                  <style></style>
                  <td>{{script.document_id}}</td>
                  {% endif %}
                  <td><small><a href = "{% url 'script:script_detail' script.pk %}">View</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="{% url "script:script_update" script.pk %}">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'label:product_label' script.pk %}">Lab Label</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'label:dispense_label' script.pk %}">Dispense Label
                  </a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'label:shipping_label' script.pk %}">Shipping Label</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url "label:receipt" script.pk %}" >Health Fund Receipt</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="{% url "label:repeat" script.pk %}">Repeat</a><!--0&nbsp;{% if script.patient.target_species == 'A' %}|&nbsp;<a href = "{% url 'communication:send_counselling_email' script.pk %} ">Counselling Email</a>{% endif %}--></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <script>
              document.querySelectorAll('#example1 a.edit').forEach(function(a) {
                a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  const url = this.dataset.url;
                  window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=250");
                });
              });
            </script>
          </div>```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Kind Regards,
AC
````

Comment: Unless the django template code is directly relevant please post the result instead, that way we can check the code directly. You should also remove all irrelevant code from the question. The less busywork we have to do the more likely you are to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Also, did you try to solve this step-by-step? I mean it sounds like the first step is obviously to find out the state of the Model. I assume it's in some table cell but I'm too lazy to look through scrolling template code.

Comment: I agree we need to get the state of the model.  I am just not sure if it should be done in the view of the template.  I am drawing a blank.  I suspect the template is probably  better done using javascript but I am not sure how?

Comment: You can extract the state inside the forEach loop that is adding the click listener. You just need to get from the <a> element to whatever element can be used to determine the model's state. But yes, you can of course also do this server-side; the easiest way is to loop over the data before you're rendering the template and to simply change the url accordingly. Of you can use [`{% if ...`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#tags) to render a different url inside the template.

Comment: Hi Chris, Using a number of opened and closed  if statements got it done.  I am not sure why it didn't work in the first place but it go there in the end.  Thankyou for your assistance.